# Excel Python while loop won't execute

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

When I test here it works perfectly fine

```
import openpyxl, pprint
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15, 12), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.close()

wb = load_workbook('test_1.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']
my_list = []
for j in range(2, 8):
    my_list.append(sheet1.cell(row = 7, column = j).value)

def Standardized_C3():
        """=(AR2-MIN(AR$2:AR$17))/(MAX(AR$2:AR$17)-MIN(AR$2:AR$17))"""
        ar = 2
        while ar < sheet1.max_row:
            for rowNum in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):  # skip the first row
                sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=46).value = ('=IFERROR((AR' + str(ar) + '-MIN(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + '))/(MAX(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + 
                                                            ')-MIN(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + ')),"null")')
                ar+= 1
    Standardized_C3()
```

But when I use the exact same loop in a large data set it seems to just go on forever. I don't understand I have let the loop go on for 10+ mins.

```
def Standardized_C3():
    """=(AR2-MIN(AR$2:AR$15100))/(MAX(AR$2:AR$15100)-MIN(AR$2:AR$15100))"""
    ar = 2
    while ar < sheet1.max_row:
        for rowNum in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):  # skip the first row
            sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=46).value = ('=IFERROR((AR' + str(ar) + '-MIN(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + '))/(MAX(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + 
                                                        ')-MIN(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + ')),"null")')
            ar+= 1
Standardized_C3()
```

Found the error:
`str(sheet1.max_row)` goes on forever need to `x = sheet1.max_row` then add `str(x)` to the formula

Answer (score 0):

Try to use print for debug

for example :

```
def Standardized_C3():
    """=(AR2-MIN(AR$2:AR$15100))/(MAX(AR$2:AR$15100)-MIN(AR$2:AR$15100))"""
    for rowNum in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):  # skip the first row
        print(rowNum)
        sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=46).value = ('=IFERROR((AR' + str(ar) + '-MIN(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + '))/(MAX(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + 
                                                    ')-MIN(AR$2:AR$' + str(sheet1.max_row) + ')),"null")')
Standardized_C3()
```

and see where script "freeze"

Comment: try to use print for debug

Comment: ah thank you this helps I can check one by one. Hopefully I see where bug is.

Comment: I found the error `str(sheet1.max_row)` goes on forever. I have to first store it as a variable. `x = sheet1.max_row` then add it to the formula as str(x)